# Get List of Integers from array of Strings

Tags: java, collections, stream

I would like to make my code look more efficient. Currently I got something like this:

```
private static String[] getAllFilesFromDirectory(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    String fileNamePattern = file.getName() + ".*\\.[0-9]*\\.GOOD";
    File dir = new File(file.getParent());

    String[] files = dir.list((currDir, currName) -> currName.matches(fileNamePattern));

    return files;
}
private static List<Integer> getAllFileNumbers(String path) {
    String[] files = getAllFilesFromDirectory(path);
    List<Integer> fileNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String currentFile : files) {
        fileNumbers.add(extractFileNumber(currentFile));
    }

    return fileNumbers;
}

private static Integer extractFileNumber(String fileName) {
    return Integer.parseInt(fileName.split("\\.")[2]);
}
```

First thing first. To `getAllFileNumbers` method I am passing path to directory, after that I am getting array of files in this directory with specific pattern. And from every file I need to extract number. 
Example:

```
test.txt.1.fail
test2.txt.2.good
test3.pdf.1.good
```

Here I am returning list of following numbers : `1, 2, 1`.

What I would like to change? Probably use stream api instead of foreach loop.
First idea was something like this:

```
Arrays.stream(files).map(this::extractFileNumber).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But because the methods are static i cant use it like this.
Obviously I could move `extractFileNumber` inside of lambda but I would like to keep my method separately.

Maybe someone has other ideas, please feel free to post any ideas. Cheers!

Comment: "I would like to make my code *look more efficient*". Simply change the method name to `extractFileNumberSuperFast`

Comment: But seriously, focusing on writing the shortest possible code is a dubious goal. It will lead to writing code that is harder to read. Code is changed infrequently and read frequently. Your #1 priority should be to ensure that it's maintainable, not concise. In this situation, the stream solution is both shorter and just as readable. To use a static method reference, use the class name instead of `this`: `MyClass::extractFileNumber`

Comment: Can you post this please `getAllFilesFromDirectory`?

Comment: @Micheal you were right with the answer.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I did add the method to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stream api can make it shorter, suppose `extractFileNumber` is in class `Main`:

```
return Stream.of(files).map(Main::extractFileNumber).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Actually `Stream#of` effectively calls `Arrays#stream` underneath, so I'm failing to see how this is an improvement. If not this example is wrong semantic wise. `Stream#of` should be used for an ad-hoc creation of a stream from an array of elements (it's a static creator afterall). `Arrays#stream` is much more descriptive when operating with arrays. Finally `Stream#of` should be used with caution especially with primitive types. For arrays at least, you should prefer `Arrays#stream`.